# django test RequestFactory cannot get route parameter to work

Tags: python, django

I have a problem that I don't know how to make it work.

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'athletes/search$', SearchAthletes.as_view()),
    url(r'athletes/([0-9]+)$', ViewAthlete.as_view())
]
```

views.py:

```
class ViewAthlete(APIView):

    def get(self, request, id, format=None):
        athlete = Athlete.objects.get(id=id)
        serializer = AthleteSerializer(athlete)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

test.py:

```
def test_view_athlete(self):
    tmp = Athlete.objects.order_by('?')[0]

    request = self.factory.get('/_api/v1/athletes/' + str(tmp.id))
    request.user = AnonymousUser()

    response = ViewAthlete.as_view()(request)
    self.assertEquals(response.data.id, tmp.id)
```

I keep getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/tests.py", line 44, in test_view_athlete
>       response = ViewAthlete.as_view()(request)
>
> File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
>       return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
>       return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 474, in dispatch
>       response = self.handle_exception(exc)
>
> File "/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 471, in dispatch
>       response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'

To my understanding, the problem is that, there is no `id` parameter passed to `get` function of `ViewAthelete` view class. What is the reason for this? In development environment (not testing), it displays the data but testing environment doesn't recognize the arguments from the route.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As zsepi says, your URLs aren't used here. To avoid repeating the arguments, rather than calling the view directly you could use the test client to "call" the URL: another advantage of doing this is that the middleware runs, so you don't need to assign the user attribute separately.

```
response = self.client.get('/_api/v1/athletes/' + str(tmp.id))
```

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK `urlpatterns` are considered when testing through the full django request stack, e.g.: through `django.test.Client`, using it's `get`/`post` methods

When testing your view directly (`MyView.as_view()(request)`) the whole url resolver logic is bypassed, and then the `args`/`kwargs` need to be supplied by the caller (e.g.: `MyView.as_view()(request, 'arg1', 'arg2', id='34')`)